# Showing $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty\\n\;\text{even}}\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}\cdot\left(\sqrt{n}+\frac{3}{4\sqrt{n}}\right)$

Tags: limits, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

It is obsevered that:

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty\\n\;\text{even}}\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}\cdot\left(\sqrt{n}+\frac{3}{4\sqrt{n}}\right) \tag{1}$$

Above is from:

$$
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}=\lim_{n \rightarrow +\infty\\\\n\  even}\frac{n!!}{(n+1)!!}\cdot\frac{1+(n+2)\cdot(\frac{1}{2!}+(n+4)\cdot(\frac{1}{4!}+(n+6)\cdot(\frac{1}{6!}+......)))}{1+(n+3)\cdot(\frac{1}{3!}+(n+5)\cdot(\frac{1}{5!}+(n+7)\cdot(\frac{1}{7!}+......)))} \tag{2}
$$

What is the steps from $(2)$ to $(1)$?

I try search the net,$\sqrt{\pi},\ \sqrt{\frac{\pi e}{2}}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ is fully discussed,but find nothing related $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$.

Comment: Stirling's approximation would suffice, but if you would like to prove it from earlier principles you can convert the limit into an integral

Comment: Your limit is $$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{n \to  + \infty } \frac{1}{{2n + 1}}\frac{{4^n }}{{\binom{2n}{n}}}\sqrt {2n} \left( {1 + \frac{3}{{8n}}} \right).
$$ Now use the asymptotics $$
\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{{4^n }}{{\sqrt {\pi n} }}.
$$

Comment: You can drop the fraction inside the parenthesis, it is neglectable. I bet that this limits is related to the Wallis product.